# How do I create rq workers for my flask application for users online? (using redis server)

Tags: python, flask, redis

I am confused about how rq workers work! I created a flask web application that runs a background process on a redis server and then returns the results. So far, during development I have been starting rq worker processes on my machine using a command line. However, now I'm ready to launch my application online. But when a remote user tries to run the application online, where are the workers hosted?

I tried initiating them directly in my code using `with Connection():` and it worked but it also interrupted the process of initiating the web application to run in my browser.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: To make my question more specific, I have launched an rq worker using the command line on my machine, but when I initiate tasks on my remote redis server (hosted on AWS EC2) the app stalls and there is no worker activity. Is there something wrong with the configuration of my rq workers or is there another way I should be launching them? All I did was `import rq` and then run `rq worker simulator` and that was enough for local development; if there is configuration that I need to change do I do so in command line?

EDIT 2: I got it working. I simply needed to run `rq worker simulator --url {ec2 address}`. Thanks Paul Becotte for the explanation pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If this question gets reopened, please move your solution in "Edit 2" to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally with a task queue (am only vaguely familiar with rq- excuse me for lack of specifics, but don't think they're necessary here) the idea is to split work out of the request/response cycle. You don't want requests that take 30 seconds- especially when you have other requests coming in!

In this world, you have a source of state (redis) and a bunch of clients that use it. Your users connect to your api to send requests. Your api connects to the source of state. For this, there are probably two endpoints- start task and check status. Your api sends a message to the pub/sub on "start task" and looks for the result of that task when check status is called.

You can also start X worker processes. They connect to redis as well as subscribers. When a task goes in, a worker picks it up and works it, then posts the result back to redis. You run enough of these processes to keep the total cycle time low with your traffic.

You don't store any state at all in any of the workers or api endpoints, so you can scale them out horizontally- start as many as you want on as many machines as you want. The only thing you need to maintain then is your redis server- make sure it is stable and backed up and everything (you can cluster redis as well and get HA, but that's a longer discussion).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarity. Sure enough once I got the redis server running my workers weren't properly communicating with it, but your response points me in the right troubleshooting direction. I think I need to make sure that the connection the workers are using to the server is defined properly. Much appreciated